# Sequelize - beforeCreate not being called

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a user model with sequelize in nodejs, but it doesn't seem that my beforeCreate isn't actually being called. I have looked at the documentation and multiple examples on the internet but I can't get it working.

The model code is as follows:

```
"use strict";
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        },
        emailAddress: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        lastLogin: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: true
        }
    });

    function cryptPassword(password, callback) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(process.env.SALT_ROUNDS, function(err, salt) {
            if (err)
                return callback(err);

            bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                return callback(err, hash);
            });
        });
    };

    User.beforeCreate(function(model, options) {
        cryptPassword(model.password, function(err, hash) {

            model.password = hash;
        });
    });

    return User;
};
```

Comment: How do you use your User model?

Answer (score 2):

you should define your hook inside of your model

```
var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: ...
}, {
    hooks: {
        beforeCreate: function(){...}
    }
});
```